# Confirm Delete with Password in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, passwords

I have a need to have my users enter their passwords when confirming a delete action. However I do not know how to compare their input to their passwords.
My algorithm is something like:

```
read passwordFieldText
if userpassword == passwordFieldText
{
   execute delete action
} 
else return "incorrect password"
```

I know of course that there is no way to retrieve a user's password as a variable, so how do I go about achieving this?

Comment: How are you storing passwords?  What makes you say `there is no way to retrieve a user's password as a variable`?  How are you logging them in, if you can't compare passwords?

Comment: Can't you just use the MVC authorize attribute on the delete controller?

Comment: I use SimpleMembership, the one that's built in to MVC 4. If I could retrieve a user's password that's been hashed from the database, that would be highly unethical.

Comment: you should hash the password they input, and compare it, just like logging in.  But really you should follow @woutervs idea

Comment: Jonesy I don't know if you've ever used WebSecurity but all of that is automated behind the scenes, in the most secure way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't compare their input to their password yourself. You pass their username and what they are now saying their password is into Membership.ValidateUser.

```
   if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
      // Do Delete
   else
      // Don't do Delete
```

Documentation can be found at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: brilliant thank you. nobody else seemed to understand my question.

Comment: If user name and password is same, then how it done?

Comment: Sorry Ramesh, I don't understand your question. If the username and password is the same as what??

Answer (score 0):

You are going wrong. because if same password have two different user, then delete action is call unrelated :p . It's tooo bad

So you need

```
read passwordFieldText
if userid=currentuserId && userpassword == passwordFieldText
{
   execute delete action

//delete action look like

delete from user where userid=currentuserId  and userpassword == passwordFieldText
} 
else return "incorrect password"
```

and how can check your password

see this samples

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/689801/Understanding-and-Using-Simple-Membership-Provider

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664294/ASP-NET-MVC-Configuring-ASP-NET-MVC-4-Membership-w

**Update**

You can get, how to check the password mach or email mach in membership table by this link

http://www.itorian.com/2013/03/PasswordResetting.html

Comment: Well obviously, I figured that was kind of implied. That doesn't answer my question.